# Android - How to transfer file between server and client

Tags: android, video, client-server

i want to create client-server apps, where client using `Android` and Server using Web Apps.

the question is, How to transfer video file from Server to all client ?

at the server, we're doing upload video files and client receive update (files). i assume this, client can download using cloud help, but i dont know what technology can be used at this.

Comment: you can look into push notification. all the registered devices will get a notification when there is a update in server and user can download/update the video files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a use case for Google's Cloud Storage for Firebase:

https://firebase.google.com/products/storage/